# How to remove the header space on Sencha GXT Grid?

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

The Grid should have a vertical scrollbar, but is hidden.
However, there is an space left on the table header.

How to remove the blank space header ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to override the GridView to set the space to 0.

```
public class CustomGxtGridView<M> extends GridView<M> {

    private static int SCROLL_OFFSET = 1;

    public CustomGxtGridView(...) {
        super(viewMediator);
        this.scrollOffset = SCROLL_OFFSET;
        this.vbar = false;
        this.setAdjustForHScroll(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getScrollAdjust() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```